# What is the best way to communicate two Angular components?

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently working on an app built with Angular 1.x and I would like to know which is the best practice to **communicate two different components** which were originally working separately in another module of the app. One of them is a selector and the other one is a slider.

Basically, the **selector** is a directive with the functionality defined in link. The same for the **slider**. The idea is to update the slider with new items everytime I click one of the options (ng-click) in the selector.

This is the very first time I have to implement this communication concept in Angular and I don't know if it's better to work with an external **service** taking and storing the data from both components, use **events** or **controllers** within the directives. Any recommendation is welcome.

**EDIT:**

Here I show the piece of code of my selector directive. Basically what I do is to change the selection property once there is a ng-click (my toggle() funct) in link:

```
angular.module('ngExploratory')
 .directive('xplrSelector', (PATH, XplrBaseObject, IdentifierService, DataService) ->
templateUrl: "#{PATH}components/selector/selector.html"
restrict: 'E'
replace: true
transclude: true
scope:
  xplrId: '@'
  xplrJoin: '='
  headers: '='
  content: '='
  limit: '='
link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
  XplrBaseObject.extend scope, element, attrs
  scope.data = {} if not scope.data?
  scope.toggle = () ->
    scope.id = IdentifierService.initialize element
    scope.value = DataService.get scope.id
    scope.data.selected = !scope.data.selected
    scope.commit()
  return
)
```

Then, once this click/selection is done I want to run and initialize my slider component (the code for this is just too long...). All the functionality in the slider is again defined in link in the directive. There are no controllers then.

Comment: One way to do it is shared scope and a scope.watch. can you share your code for a detailed explanation

Comment: Are these components using different controllers?

Comment: recommend reading : http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/25/communication-between-collaborating-directives-in-angular/

Comment: @tylerwal They don't use controllers. All the functionality is defined in the link of each directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to use services for data (and potentially behavior) sharing. If possible I try to use the API of the service and use events as a last resort. But of course, every scenario is different... :-)

Comment: Thanks! I already started to work on a service with different functions to take data from one component, then store it and then take it from the other one. This seems more familiar than the events for now...